# WPF Custom Control does not exist in XML namespace

Tags: wpf

I'm having an annoying error that I can't seem to fix or find a solution to in my WPF project.  I have a custom WPF control that I added to my project but I can't get it to work. This is the error I am getting:

> The tag 'ZoomBorder' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Namespace1;assembly=Namespace1'. Line 8 Position 10.

Here is my xaml for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="Namespace1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace1;assembly=Namespace1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="357,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <local:ZoomBorder x:Name="border" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gray"> //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            <Image Name="DrawingImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
        </local:ZoomBorder>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have tried building, cleaning, and rebuilding with and without the offending lines and nothing has worked.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try xmlns without assembly name: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace1"`

Comment: @ASh Really weird outcome when I do this - I can hit start and the program loads & behaves as expected, but the Designer shows an error saying invalid markup and the error from before persists in the error list.

Comment: How wedded are you to the idea of using the XAML designer?  One of the first things I do when installing VS is to disable it completely.  You can get a similar effect with XAML Hot Reload

Comment: @Joe Im not at all bonded with it. I'm new to WPF, so I actually thought that it was required. Could you link me to the XAML Hot Reload thing so I could check it out?

Comment: Debug Menu >> Options >> Debugging >> XAML Hot Reload.  Check the "Enable XAML Hot Reload checkbox with at least the WPF category checked underneath it.  Then, whenever you debug, as you manually edit XAML, the changes will be reflected in the UI.  Of course you do have to manually edit XAML... you don't get to drag controls around the screen.  But it's something you need to learn anyway

Answer (score -1):

You have new visual studio and old lib. Thats mess.

Install 4.7 dev runtime:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk

Right click your project and open folder. Edit your project file to fav editor like notepad and add following lines:

```
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
<TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
```

goto where you use control and add namespace my visual studio 2022 suggest this one: <mainwindow.xaml>

```
  xmlns:paz="clr-namespace:Scar.Common.WPF.Controls;assembly=Scar.Common.WPF.Controls.ZoomBorder"
```

close visual studio and restart and compile.  Build: succeeded if you din't forget anything.

Comment: This is in visual studio 2013, not exactly new visual studio